# Blazor Server vs Blazor Web Assembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am going to create an ERP application using new .NET 5 Blazor Framework which contain 300 pages and 250 concurrent users. I would like to know which modeling hosting to be preferred for developing an ERP application: Blazor Server or Blazor Web Assembly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blazor Server App or WebAssembly will consume almost the same ressources if you keep the same functionnality level : API call and bi-directional communication (WebSocket = SignalR connection)

If you don't need WebSocket then WebAssembly scale better.

For intranet with less than 5000 concurent connection then Blazor Server is a better choice because :

- You don't need to create an API, you directly call business logic from the page code. For example cmd.ExecuteQuery(). Developing an API is a huge dev task and look at gRPC to ease the task.
- You can debug like a WinForm app and this is precious. Not using an API makes debugging even easier

WebSocket is better for CPU intensive processing that can run on the client side or site that call a very few API